# Check for each unique value we have same unique id

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyr

I have a excel sheet which looks like:

```
Col1    Col2
IJ-123  A2B1
IJ-123  A2B1
IJ-456  C2C2
IJ-456  c2c2
IJ-456  D1e2
IJ-789  LJ87
IJ-456  
IJ-789  LJ98

x = data.frame(
  Col1 = c("IJ-123", "IJ-123", "IJ-456", "IJ-456", 
           "IJ-456", "IJ-789", "IJ-456", "IJ-789"), 
  Col2 = c("A2B1", "A2B1", "C2C2", "c2c2",
           "D1e2", "LJ87", NA, "LJ98")
)
```

I want to add one more column and check (for each Unique `Col2` Value) whether the assigned values in `Col1` are `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Output:

```
Col1    Col2  Result
IJ-123  A2B1  TRUE
IJ-123  A2B1  TRUE
IJ-456  C2C2  TRUE
IJ-456  c2c2  TRUE
IJ-456  D1e2  FALSE
IJ-789  LJ87  TRUE (Because Col2 count=1 for this value)
IJ-456        C2C2
IJ-789  LJ98  TRUE (Because Col2 count=1 for this value)
```

Logic:

1. If there are more than 1 of the value in col2, then check that the 
   corresponding col1 values just for those col2 values are the same
2. If there is only one of the col2 values then check that the col1 is unique 
   but only against the col1 values of multiple-occurring col2 values.
3. Some field are blank in `Col2` for those if we have have duplicate `Col1` 
   value than show `Col2` value mapped to those `Col1` in Result (see Row 7).

For this i have a excel formula `=IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$8,B2)=1,SUMPRODUCT(--(($A$2:$A$8=A2)*(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$8,$B$2:$B$8))>1))=0,COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$8,B2,$A$2:$A$8,"<>"&A2)=0)` but its working very slow since waiting for ~4 hours it only complete 28% processing on ~0.2 million data.

I have uploaded the file in `csv` format on R and want to carry out the same exercise on R for faster processing.

Comment: I don't follow your logic for making assignments to the `Result` column.  Please explain this better.  But good idea ditching Excel for R.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  In simple i want to check that for every >1 same `Col2` value i should have same `Col1` and for every `Col2` value =1 or <1 there should be unique `Col1` value in entire excel sheet. And wherever the `Col2` vaule is blank and if found the assigned `Col1` value is duplicate than if we have `Col2` value for that particular `Col1` vaule than show that value in `Result` (i.e Row 7).

Comment: it's very odd to me that you want to mix TRUE/FALSE with the implied missing value from Col2... why not just back-fill that value to Col2 instead of polluting your new column?

Comment: @MichaelChirico In that case I wouldn't be able to find the count of error that i can see in my existing Dataframe.

Comment: add a separate (fourth) column as a "flag" indicating that you've altered the original data

Comment: @MichaelChirico That would work.

Comment: @MichaelChirico Any luck here??

Comment: a question : `IJ-456  D1e2  FALSE` - does this mean that a value of D1e2 is appearing at least one more time in your data?

Comment: @Tjebo No... Because IJ-456 is associated with C2C2 unique value.

Comment: How do you identify then to which value of Col2 the Col1- value should belong ?

Comment: Also, is the letter case of importance?

Comment: @Tjebo In a ideal scenario for each unique`Col2` Value there should be unique`Col1` value. For example if any other entry come in `Col2` as C2C2 or c2c2 it should be mapped to IJ-456 only.

Comment: My question was not clear enough then. In your example data, you have two col2 values for IJ-456. The same for IJ-789, but there are only one value of col2 per col1 value here. Assigning 'False' to D1e2 means, that you must have decided that you want C2C2 to be TRUE and not D1e2  - I just wondered how you decided that

Comment: @Tjebo No... Since I'm checking here for multiple `Col2` there should be same `Col1` Value and here C2C2 meet that criteria.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165367/discussion-between-tjebo-and-roy1245).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try dplyr:

```
require(dplyr)
x$Col2 <- toupper(x$Col2) #make all letters same case.

x_assigned <- x %>% group_by(Col2,Col1) %>% 

summarise(n = n()) %>% #counts the number of occurrences
  group_by(Col1) %>% arrange(desc(n)) %>%  # arranges so that the highest count per Col1 is first
  mutate(assigned = if (first(n) == 1) { #this conditional statement will assign the 'correct' Col2 value to your Col1 value
      Col2
    } else if (first(n) > 1) { 
      first(Col2)
    },
  test = assigned == Col2)

x_assigned

# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   Col1 [3]
  Col2  Col1      n assigned test 
  <chr> <chr> <int> <chr>    <lgl>
1 A2B1  I-123     2 A2B1     T    
2 C2C2  I-456     2 C2C2     T    
3 D1E2  I-456     1 C2C2     F    
4 LJ87  I-789     1 LJ87     T    
5 LJ98  I-789     1 LJ98     T    
6 <NA>  I-456     1 C2C2     NA
```

in order to get your required results, you can make a simple left join of x and x_assigned:

```
left_join(x, x_assigned, by = c('Col1', 'Col2'))
```

you can this way see where you have missing values and also easily assign your 'correct' Col2 value. Apologies if I should have misunderstood your question, I still am not sure about how you assign the 'correct' Col2 value to a Col1 value

Answer (score 1):

As always, I recommend using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x) # convert your data.frame to data.table to unlock syntax
# convert to lowercase
x[ , Col2 := tolower(Col2)]
# count how many observations are associated with each Col2 value
x[ , col2_count := .N, by = Col2]

# first deal with rows where Col2 is non-missing
x[!is.na(Col2), Result := {
  # when there's more than one value in Col2,
  #   TRUE if and only if there's exactly one unique value in Col1
  if (.N > 1) uniqueN(Col1) == 1L
  # otherwise, TRUE if and only if Col1 is _not_ found among the
  #   Col1 values associated with the Col2 rows for which there are
  #   multiple observations of that Col2 (i.e, col2_count > 1)
  else !Col1 %in% x[col2_count > 1, unique(Col1)]
}, by = Col2]

# now, deal with the missing rows case, adding a flag to
#   record that we've done so
x[is.na(Col2), c('Col2', 'col2_flag') :=
    # use the rows of the subset data.table to look up
    #   the non-missing rows from X with the same Col1,
    #   and take the _first_ observed value of Col2
    x[!is.na(Col1)][copy(.SD), .(Col2, TRUE), on = 'Col1', mult = 'first']
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by aggregating the data and adding these as two additional columns:

```
library(dplyr)

# Create dummy dataframe
Col1 <- c("IJ-123", "IJ-123", "IJ-456", "IJ-456", "IJ-456", "IJ-789", "IJ-456", "IJ-789") 
Col2 <- c("A2B1", "A2B1", "C2C2", "c2c2", "D1e2", "LJ87", "C2C2", "LJ98")
df <- data.frame(Col1, Col2)

# Aggregate data - Col2 Vs Col1 and Col1 Vs Col2
Col2vsCol1 <- aggregate(Col1 ~ Col2, data = df, paste, collapse = ",")
colnames(Col2vsCol1)[2] <- "Col2vsCol1"
Col1vsCol2 <- aggregate(Col2 ~ Col1, data = df, paste, collapse = ",")
colnames(Col1vsCol2)[2] <- "Col1vsCol2"
# Outer join these as two extra columns to original df:
df <- merge(x = df, y = Col2vsCol1, by = "Col2", all = TRUE)
df <- merge(x = df, y = Col1vsCol2, by = "Col1", all = TRUE)
```

You can then use these columns to perform your logical check against:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+
|   Col1   Col2    Col2vsCol1          Col1vsCol2          |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| 1 IJ-123 A2B1    IJ-123,IJ-123       A2B1,A2B1           |
| 2 IJ-123 A2B1    IJ-123,IJ-123       A2B1,A2B1           |
| 3 IJ-456 c2c2    IJ-456              C2C2,c2c2,D1e2,C2C2 |
| 4 IJ-456 C2C2    IJ-456,IJ-456       C2C2,c2c2,D1e2,C2C2 |
| 5 IJ-456 C2C2    IJ-456,IJ-456       C2C2,c2c2,D1e2,C2C2 |
| 6 IJ-456 D1e2    IJ-456              C2C2,c2c2,D1e2,C2C2 |
| 7 IJ-789 LJ87    IJ-789              LJ87,LJ98           |
| 8 IJ-789 LJ98    IJ-789              LJ87,LJ9898         |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I have already considered the aggregate method but since the i have thousands of `Col1` value associated with `Col2` and vice versa, i found that this method is not that useful for the analysis.

Comment: Thanks by the way.

Comment: @Graeme why `require(dplyr)` - this code looks like base R to me :)